# Differences between Rs deSolve and Pythons odeint

Tags: python, r, odeint, desolve

I'm currently exploring the Lorenz system with `Python` and `R` and have noticed subtle differences in the `ode` packages. [`odeint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) from `Python` and [`ode`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/deSolve/versions/1.28/topics/ode) both say they use `lsoda` to calculate their derivatives. However, using the `lsoda` command for both seems to give far different results. I have tried `ode45` for the `ode` function in `R` to get something more similar to `Python` but am wondering why I can't get exactly the same results:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
def lorenz(x, t):
    return [
        10 * (x[1] - x[0]),
        x[0] * (28 - x[2]) - x[1],
        x[0] * x[1] - 8 / 3 * x[2],
    ]


dt = 0.001
t_train = np.arange(0, 0.1, dt)
x0_train = [-8, 7, 27]
x_train = odeint(lorenz, x0_train, t_train)


x_train[0:5, :]
array([[-8.        ,  7.        , 27.        ],
       [-7.85082366,  6.98457874, 26.87275343],
       [-7.70328919,  6.96834721, 26.74700467],
       [-7.55738803,  6.95135316, 26.62273959],
       [-7.41311133,  6.93364263, 26.49994363]])
```

```
library(deSolve)
n <- round(100, 0)
# Lorenz Parameters: sigma, rho, beta
parameters <- c(s = 10, r = 28, b = 8 / 3)
state <- c(X = -8, Y = 7, Z = 27) # Initial State
# Lorenz Function used to generate Lorenz Derivatives
lorenz <- function(t, state, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
    dx <- parameters[1] * (state[2] - state[1])
    dy <- state[1] * (parameters[2] - state[3]) - state[2]
    dz <- state[1] * state[2] - parameters[3] * state[3]
    list(c(dx, dy, dz))
  })
}
times <- seq(0, ((n) - 1) * 0.001, by = 0.001)
# ODE45 used to determine Lorenz Matrix
out <- ode(y = state, times = times,
           func = lorenz, parms = parameters, method = "ode45")[, -1]
out[1:nrow(out), , drop = FALSE]
             X        Y        Z
 [1,] -8.00000000 7.000000 27.00000
 [2,] -7.85082366 6.984579 26.87275
 [3,] -7.70328918 6.968347 26.74700
 [4,] -7.55738803 6.951353 26.62274
 [5,] -7.41311133 6.933643 26.49994
```

I had to call `out[1:nrow(out), , drop = FALSE]` to get the fully provided decimal places, it appears that `head` rounds to the nearest fifth. I understand it's incredibly subtle, but was hoping to get the exact same results. Does anyone know if this is something more than a rounding issue between `R` and `Python`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All numerical methods that solve ODEs are approximations that work up to a given precision. The precision of the deSolve solvers is set to `atol=1e-6, rtol=1e-6` by default, where `atol` is absolute and `rtol` is relative tolerance. Furthermore, `ode45` has some additional parameters to fine-tune the automatic step size algorithm, and it can make use of interpolation.

To increase tolerance, set for example:

```
out <- ode(y = state, times = times, func = lorenz, 
  parms = parameters, method = "ode45", atol = 1e-10, rtol = 1e-10)
```

Finally, I would recommend to use an odepack solver like `lsoda` or `vode` instead of the classical `ode45`. More details can be found in the `ode` and `lsoda` help pages and for `ode45` in the ?rkMethod help page.

Similar parameters may also exist for `odeint`.

A final note: as Lorenz is a chaotic system, local errors will lead to diverging behaviour due to error magnification. This is an essential feature of chaotic systems, which are by theory unpredictable on the long run. So whatever you do, and how much precision you set, simulated trajectories are not "the real ones", they just show a similar pattern.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to take your advice and use `lsoda` for both packages and reproduce the same results for the `X` variable by adjusting the tolerance figures to what `odeint` has as its default. However, why do `Y` and `Z` still give different results?

Comment: is `odeint` using the same tolerances as `ode()` ?

Comment: I changed the tolerances based on the `odeint` tolerances which are `1.49012e-8`

Comment: The implementation of `ode45` differs between Python and R, they just uses the same Runge-Kutta pair (Dormand-Prince 4, 5). In contrast, `lsoda` is the odepack algorithm, but it was also somewhat modified for R to allow additional features. Not sure if this changes the "exact" tolerance, but this is in general not of interest, as all solvers are approximations anyway. The good news is, that all solvers in deSolve underwent heavy benchmarking, see examples in package **deTestSet**.

Comment: But: note the edit regarding chaotic systems!

Comment: Thanks, so the issue was the tolerances weren't the same, the rest could be because of every so subtle differences in the results which could occur because of rounding or solvers between `R` and `Python`?

Comment: Yes, due to rounding, subtle differences in the algorithm and (most important) error magnification by the chaotic system.

Comment: Another comment: R's **deSolve** uses "fail-safe" defaults for the maximal internal time step `hmax`, derived from the external step size in `times`. This decision was made to avoid pitfalls with non-autonomous systems that have external forcings. As a side effect, deSolve is sometimes more precise than requested by atol and rtol, at the cost of a smaller internal stepsize. This can be overwritten by setting `hmax` (and `hini`) to values larger than the step size given in `times`.